# ANT. Sign jars if have not been signed

Tags: loops, ant

I have an application which contains much jars.
However, the jars are upload to subversion, but I need build an ant that only sign the jars if no have been signed.

The idea is verify each jar contained into defined fileset and sign if not have been signed, but I dont know how I can execute a instruction for each file at a specified path.

Very thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Apply](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) task to execute a system command for every file in a resource collection (e.g. a fileset).

You can test whether a jar is signed or not by looking in its META-INF dir. See the [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) documentation for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can just execute the `SignJar` task with your fileset, by default it will not sign JAR files that are already signed.
See [the doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/signjar.html) for confirmation - note that the `force` attribute introduced with Ant 1.8 defaults to `false`, that is to say, in previous versions if the file was not signed it would not sign it.

(I'm assuming here that you mean "If I have already signed the file then don't sign it again", and not "Don't sign the file as me if anybody else has signed it".)